# Debugging WP8 Native Code using a file

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a WP8 app that has some native code (runtime component).
Inside the runtime component I need to check to content of a c style array.
Because this array is not small, I thought the best I could do is write the array in a file
using fopen/fwrite/fclose;
Checking the returned value from fopen and fwrite, I can see that it succeeded.
But I cannot find the file (using Windows Phone Power Tools).

So where has the file been written?
Is there another way to dump the content of the array to a file (on the computer) from visual studio ?

Comment: Did you restart Windows Phone Power Tools? Unfortunately it doesn't refresh automatically to pick up on IsoStore changes.

Comment: Justin: Yes that is the first thing I have tried. There's also a "refresh" contexmenu button, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with the fopen/fwrite/fclose APIs in WP8. Which probably means it's not a whitelisted API you can use to submit your app with. It's best if you just use "Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder" when working with IsoStore in C++. See Win8 code sample @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: how do you know that fopen/fwrite/fclose are blacklisted ?

Comment: @entropy I doubt they are - Microsoft would cause a riot among C developers for blacklisting part of the standard library...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Justin,

here's how I ended up doing it:

```
auto folder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
Concurrency::task<Windows::Storage::StorageFile^> createFileOp(
    folder->CreateFileAsync(L"Data.bin", Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting));

createFileOp.then(
    [nData, pData](Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file)
    {
        return file->OpenAsync(Windows::Storage::FileAccessMode::ReadWrite);
    })
    .then([nData, pData](Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ stream)
        {
            auto buffer = ref new Platform::Array<BYTE>(pData, nData);

            auto outputStream = stream->GetOutputStreamAt(0);
            auto dataWriter = ref new Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter(outputStream);                        
            dataWriter->WriteBytes(buffer);

            return dataWriter->StoreAsync();
        })
   .wait();
```

Now compare that to what I "meant" :

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Data.bin", "wb");
if (fp)
{
    int ret = fwrite(pData, 1, nData, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```