# WP8 differences between file manipulation APIs in fileapi.h and stdio.h?

Tags: file, windows-phone-8, location, stdio, fileapi

According to [Supported Win32 APIs for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), WP8 does support many file manipulation APIs in `fileapi.h` like CreateFile2, ReadFile, WriteFile, ...

But when I include `<stdio.h>` I can use fopen, fread, fwrite, ...

Using both those APIs, I can create and read/write to a text file.

```
CreateFile2("hello.txt", ...);
fopen("hello.txt", ...);
```

*... means other parameters, which aren't important to this question*.

The other thing is that I don't know where that text file resides. Installed location isn't the case, because it is read-only location. The other case is Local folder, but I don't specify any Local folder path.

So what are the differences between those APIs (in `fileapi.h` and `stdio.h`) and which location does they act on ?

**P/S:** I'm doing in the WP Runtime Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is the API set these functions use.

`<stdio.h>` contains the file APIs of the standard C library, `<fileapi.h>` is the Win32 APIs. There are also C++ APIs (`<iostream>`) which you could use.

I've found that whatever API you use, you should explicitly set the file location to the Local folder.

```
Platform::String^ localfolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;
Platform::String^ myFileName = Platform::String::Concat(localfolder, "\\myfile.txt");
```

One thing to watch is that `Platform::String^` uses  `wchar_t`, not `char` internally so you need to be a bit careful in specifying the file name.

So, try and find an API that takes `wchar_t*` for the file name and use that to avoid having to do character set conversion.

E.g.: Use `_wfsopen` instead of `fopen`.

Comment: So these 2 APIs set are the same in WP8? If I don't explicitly set file location, I just use fopen, I can't figure out where that file resides !

Comment: Yes I saw that too (although I think it was with the C++ iostream APIs). I fixed it by explicitly setting the full path as shown above.

Comment: Someone already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308300/debugging-wp8-native-code-using-a-file but no answers found

Comment: That answer's another option - you can use the Windows Runtime file APIs, but it's advanced, probably overkill - do you really want to get your head around the C++ 11 concurrency stuff too?

Comment: I just want to mention that we can't find where file created with fopen/CreateFileAsync resides (without explicitly specifying the path)

Comment: I've no idea either - and neither did the other questioner. Hence why I recommended that you explicitly set the location :)